# How can I input growth rates and the rolling window standard deviation of yearly sales data in R?

Tags: r, database, time-series, standard-deviation

I have this dataset which includes all the sales for a company in a given year (company code = gvkey, year = fyearq, sales = saley). I want to examine the volatility of these sales, which is defined as a time series of standard deviations of ten-year rolling windows of the sales growth rates(x). I also need to calculate the growth rates in order to do this.

Mathematically, the time series for the volatility would look like this:

[image: time series forvolatility]

where the "average x" is the average of x between t-4 and t+5.

How can I input this in R? And how can I calculate the growth rates I need?

An example of the data i am working with looks like this:

```
        gvkey   fyearq      saley
1        1004    1978     26.669
2        1004    1979     32.563
3        1004    1980     30.454
4        1004    1981     41,766
5        1004    1982     40.465
6        1004    1983     40.475
7        1004    1984     52.723
8        1004    1985     53.386
9        1004    1986     66.376
10       1004    1987     74.543
11       1004    1988     90.007
12       1004    1989     108.635
13       1004    1990     116.092
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that ia doing what you want

```
# create data
n <- 100
saley <- rnorm(n, 100, 5)
gvkey <- factor(c(rep("A", n/2), rep("B", n/2)))
fyearq <- c(1980:(1980+n/2-1), 1992:(1992+n/2-1))
df <- data.frame(saley, gvkey, fyearq)

# function for growth ratea
growth_rate <- function(x){
 out <- c(NA,  x[2:length(x)]/ x[1:(length(x)-1)])
return(out)
}

# function for volatility  
volatility <- function(x){
out <- rep(NA, length(x))
for(i in (1+4):(length(x)-5)){
out[i] <- sqrt((x[i] - mean(x[(i-4):(i+5)]))**2 /10)
}
return(out)
}

# apply function for growth rates
df$growth_rate <- do.call("c", by(df$saley, df$gvkey, growth_rate))

# applying function for volatility
df$volatility <- do.call("c", by(df$growth_rate, df$gvkey, volatility))

df
```

I tried to answer the question although to me this is not a good question since it asks for a complete method rather than asking something specific about programming with R. The benefit for others reading this is little compared to programming questions which can be applied to many situations.

Comment: thank you! Would you perhaps also know, how the code for the yearly growth rates of sales would look like? Or does the first part already does this? I have to measure the volatility for those, instead of the absolute sales values.

Comment: You provided data with three columns and one formula which is supposed to be to apploed to the column saley. I am not sure what you mean with yearly growth? The change between two years?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't express myself well. I have to first compute a new column with the yearly sales growth rates for each gvkey (the percentage change between two years for sales of each gvkey), and then use these growth rates in the volatility formula.

Comment: I added that to the answer. If this answers your question consider marking my answer as answered.

Comment: Thank you very much again. It does do exactly what I meant. The only issue that I've noticed, is that the growth rates seem to be coming out wrong. An excerpt would be 

` 
           gvkey   fyearq   saley         growth_rate
1          5681     1995    21.486             1.0474
2          5681     1996    17.559             1.3617   
3          5681     1997    8.670               1.1960
4          5681     1998    12.394             1.1273

`
But we know, for instance that a percentage growth rate (or decline) from 96 to 97 should actually be -50,73% (or -0,5073)

Comment: I don't know what values that are. For gvkey1004: 1978 it was 26.669 and 1979 it was 32.563 which means a growth of 32.563/ 26.669= 1.22. This is what the function in my answer does.

Comment: Technically it does work. I've realized the only thing that is missing, is conditioning this data to each gvkey, in other words, to each company, as there are a lot more than just a few different "gvkeys". Would you know how I can implement that? I will mark your answer as answered, as it already technically did what I wanted, but would really appreciate if you could guide me on how I can condition it to different gvkeys. So basically: "compute all growth rates for this gvkey, start over for the next different gvkey".

Comment: The code already does this. This is done with the by() function where I tell R to apply the functions (growth_rate or volatility) to be applied to each gvkey separately.

Comment: In that case, I don't really know what is wrong. I don't know exactly which saley value it is diving by (although as stated in your code, it should be by the preceding value). The calculation and code are definitely right, but the output isn't, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know what of the output is not as expected. It makes more sense if you  try to understand what those functions do and ask questions about programming rather than asking for a whole complete method. The benefit for others reading this will be little compared if one asks questions about programming in R which can be applied to various situations.

Comment: Got it fixed. I only had to order the data first using [order(df$gvkey, df$fyearq, df$saley),]. Then all worked. Regarding your comment: I understand where you are coming from, and I apologize. I asked this in this specific way because I am working in an econometrics paper. Due to deadlines, I can't put much as much energy into understanding certain functions as I would like to, but believe me, I genuinely would like to. I, unfortunately, lack a lot of the basics and didn't have time to learn it in a proper way. Hopefully, after this paper, I'll have learned and improved a bit.

Comment: That was no offend so please don't take it personal. It was only my opinion which I dindn't want to leve unmentioned. I wish you all the best with the paper!

Comment: I know, just wanted to also explain myself, as I actually agree with what you said. Thank you very much again for your help!